# How to set returned value of log10(0)?

Tags: c++, double

[Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5485df2d33f7b7bf):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  double result = log10(0.0);
  cout << result;
}
```

When I execute log10(0) in C++, It prints to me `-inf`.

Is it fixed for every library/compiler I'll use?

Or could it change in different platforms?

How would you manage the `pole error` keeping `double`?

Comment: You're going to get `-inf` as long as the rules of math in this universe remain what they are right now.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You are asking four (including the title). It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Of course :) I'm asking if that message (-inf) would be change (i.e. INF, or -INF, or ISINF)

Comment: So why don't you ask that question, instead of four different ones?

Comment: "How to set returned value of log10(0)?" isn't clear enough?

Comment: @paizza: You seem to be mixing the value (negative infinity) with specific _representations of_ that value.  C++ defaults to _binary_ floating point values and _decimal_ repreresentations, but there's of course no decimal representation of (minus) infinity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log10/), it depends on the library what you get for `log10(0)`. However, in general the value of `log10(0)` is not defined (can be `-inf` if you like, but it is not a real number). Usually, you should prevent such undefined results (not undefined in the C++ sense of Undefined Behaviour, but in a mathematical sense) **before** they happen. E.g.

```
double x;
x = foo();
if ( x <= 0 ) {
    /* handle this case extra */
else {
    y = log10(x);
}
```

What value you use in the case of `log10(0)` depends very much on your application. However, I think it is easier to check for `0` before doing the calculation instead of relying on `log10(0)` returning some particular value (as it might be `-inf` or something completely different).

Comment: True, and smart! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Actually, considering the function involved, it is safe to check that `x<=0`. There is no epsilon needed. The `abs` is actively harmful, it causes the check to miss `log10(-1)`.

Comment: @MSalters I wasnt sure, actually if x is coming from some previous calculations, it might make sense to reject also input close to zero. The case of negative input i didnt include on purpose. However you are completely right and I edited the answer

Comment: @MSalters I agree, I'm also not certain how `abs` handles infinitys or NaNs. [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38329497/2642059) uses `isnormal` to cope with those.

Comment: @JonathanMee it was never meant to handle infinities or NaNs. The question specifically asks for `log10(0)` and I focused on this. Infinities and nans I would rather try to detect at the place where they happen and would not be to much concerned about having them as input

Comment: @tobi303 As you point out, surely `x` is not a literal but is coming from some previous calculations. Therefore if we're concerned with detecting 0, I think we should also be concerned with detecting other illegal inputs.

Comment: @JonathanMee Imho, this really depends. I tend to try to catch infinities of NaN before passing them as input (if possible). However, I get your point and actually I am not 100% how I would handle it in a real case. To be honest I rarely check for illegal inputs unless I have to find a bug caused by some Nan or the like.

Comment: @tobi303 "I rarely check for illegal inputs unless I have to find a bug." I resemble that remark ;) Ultimately [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38329497/2642059) is just checking for error conditions that are in addition to what the OP requested. And as we've both alluded to even this check wouldn't even naturally occur in code that either of us had written. Making this answer the closest to a natural one :)

Answer (score 3):

The behavior is very clear-cut for [`log10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log10) for floating point implementations that are IEC 60559 compliant:

> - If the argument is ±0, -∞ is returned and `FE_DIVBYZERO` is raised.
> - If the argument is 1, +0 is returned
> - If the argument is negative, NaN is returned and `FE_INVALID` is raised.
> - If the argument is +∞, +∞ is returned
> - If the argument is NaN, NaN is returned

This list would allow you to conditionally handle each case for compliant implementations. But honestly, we know that only the range (+0, +∞) is supported, so whether your implementation is compliant or not you could simply guard your `log10` with an `if`-block.

A great way to write this `if`-block is with [`isnormal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnormal) if you don't want to allow denormals or [`isfinite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite) if you do want to support denormals. For example, given a floating point variable `foo`:

```
if(isfinite(foo) && foo > 0) {
    cout << log10(foo) << endl;
} else {
    cout << "foo is invalid\n";
}
```

But **the answer to your question is no -∞ will not always be returned**. But C++ does guarantee a return: Given `log10(foo)`:

- If `foo` is a `float` the return will always be `-HUGE_VALF`
- If `foo` is a `double` the return will always be `-HUGE_VAL`
- If `foo` is a `long double` the return will always be `-HUGE_VALL`

> On implementations that support floating-point infinities, these macros always expand to the positive infinities of `float`, `double`, and `long double`, respectively <sup>[[source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/HUGE_VAL)]</sup>

Whether your implementation supports infinity or whether these values expand to the maximum floating point value, the right way to handle this is still probably `isnormal`/`isfinite` but you *could* also test the return of `log10`:

```
const auto result = log10(foo);

if(is_same_v<decltype(foo), float> && result == -HUGE_VALF ||
   is_same_v<decltype(foo), double> && result == -HUGE_VAL ||
   is_same_v<decltype(foo), long double> && result = -HUGE_VALL) {
    cout << "foo is invalid\n";
} else {
    cout << result << endl;
}
```

Comment: in the link you provided it says "If the implementation supports IEEE floating-point arithmetic (IEC 60559), [...]" not sure if there is any implementation for which this isnt true, but it seems that the standard leaves it open whether an implementation does have this behavior or not

Comment: @tobi303 Thanks for the clarification, you're right I had misinterpreted the question. I've edited.

Comment: I'm not sure about the `isnormal`. `log10(x)` is well-defined for denormal `x`; it will be `-608` or so.  I suppose you want to check if `x` is _finite_, though.

Comment: @MSalters I suppose if you happen to want to support denormals as well, you can use [`isfinite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite) instead of `isnormal`.

Answer (score 0):

Well c++ ref gives clear answer: [cpp ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log10).

> If the argument is ±0, -∞ is returned and FE_DIVBYZERO is raised.

So yes, log10(0) will give you -inf, doesn't matter what library/compiler you use (as long as it's in line with spec).

Comment: you missed the "**If** the implementation supports IEEE floating-point arithmetic (IEC 60559), [...]" part (bold emphasis added by me)

Comment: Huh, you are right. I won't delete answer, even though it's incorrect, so this info prevails. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

In math there is no option to calculate `log(0)`